# Is it possible to detect when a VOIP call starts and ends using C#?

Tags: c#, voip, skype

I would like to run a program when a Skype call ends, is there any way to detect such an action using C#.NET? Are there any libraries that can help me? I cannot find any!

Ideally, I would like to detect any VOIP type call starting/ending. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [SkypeKit](http://developer.skype.com/skypekit/reference/dotnet/html/index.html)? It allows for setting up callbacks such as these.

Answer (score 0):

I guess so. You can use Skype4COM  with the following code as a start point:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace SkypeCall
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeSkype();
        }

        private void InitializeSkype()
        {
            s = new Skype();
            _ISkypeEvents_Event events = s;

            events.AttachmentStatus += OnAttachementStatusChanged;
            events.CallStatus += OnCallStatusChanged;

            s.Attach();
        }

        private void OnCallStatusChanged(Call call, TCallStatus status)
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case TCallStatus.clsInProgress: break;
                case TCallStatus.clsCancelled: break;
                case TCallStatus.clsFinished: break;
                case TCallStatus.clsRinging: break;
                //.
                //.
                //.                 
            }


            // call.PstnNumber;
            // call.PstnStatus;
        }

        private void OnAttachementStatusChanged(TAttachmentStatus status)
        {
            if (status == TAttachmentStatus.apiAttachSuccess)
            {
                attached = true;
            }
        }


        private Skype s;
        private bool attached;
    }
}
```

and implement your logic inside OnCallStatusChanged method.